# Combinatorics problem about sum of natural numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Following combinatorics problem is claimed to be an open problem in "[The Princeton Companion to Mathematics](https://books.google.com/books/princeton?hl=en&q=%22Will%20there%20always%20be%20a%20positive%20integer%22&vid=ISBN9781400830398&btnG.x=0&btnG.y=0&btnG=Search%20This%20Book#v=snippet&q=%22Will%20there%20always%20be%20a%20positive%20integer%22&f=false)" (pp. 6)

> Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,...$ be a sequence of positive integers, and suppose that each $a_n$ lies between $n^2$ and $(n+ 1)^2$. Will there always be a positive integer that can be written in a thousand different ways as a sum of two numbers from the sequence?

I am curious to know current status and references for this problem.

Comment: Nice question! Is there anything special about "thousand"? I think you can send an email to the writers of the book for more details about this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the sequence $a_1, a_2,\dots$ has the property that each integer can be written in at most $g$ ways (counting order and allowing repetition), then we call the set $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$ a $B^\ast[g]$ set. I wrote an extensive bibliography about 10 years ago, and published it in the [Electronic Journal of Combinatorics](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS11) section on hot bibliographies. Unfortunately, I've never gotten around to updating it. For some reason, Math Sci-Net never cataloged it, either.

A related and more famous question, asked by Erdos and Turan, is if it is possible for a $B^\ast[g]$ set of nonnegative integers to also be a basis, that is, is it possible for every positive integer to have a representation while no positive integer has more than $g$ representations? The answer is known to be "no" for small $g$; the proofs are essentially a depth first search through $B^\ast[g]$ sets.

To answer the Shahrooz Janbaz's question, there is nothing too special about 1000 except that it removes "just compute all possibilities" as a possible strategy. That is, if "1000" is replaced by 4 or 5 or 6, then we could perhaps just search through all possibilities. Perhaps a clever program (SAT solver?) could handle 10 or 20. But 1000 clearly requires a deeper understanding of addition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also, I saw your paper and it is interesting. I hope you can update it asap. As I understood, this problem is open, yes? Also, the question asks about the existence of a special integer which can be written in thousand different ways. But in your definition, the sequence has this property that each integer can be written in at most $g$ ways (allowing repetition).

Comment: Either the set is a $B^*[999] $ set, or there is a positive integer with at least 1000 representations.